# How to make hyperlinks work on PDFs from MS Word for Mac

Tags: macos, ms-office, pdf, links

I am using Word 16-72 on Ventura 13.4.1.

I created a document with numerous hyperlinks to webpages and email addresses. Inside Word, I hover the mouse over the links and if I click, they work.

When I export that document to PDF, only the email links work. The webpage links appear as blue text underlined, but nothing happens if I click them.

I have the "Internet and network paths with hyperlinks" option turned on in "AutoFormat As You Type".

Comment: Are you using the “Save As” to convert to PDF or are you using Print to PDF?

Comment: Have you tried the links in the PDF with different PDF readers in order to isolate the problem? Also see [this Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/195716/359458).

Comment: Adding to what Allan said, to ensure that hyperlinks will work properly in a pdf (exported from Word), you'll need to use "Save As". Then, you'll need to click on the "Options" button and look for an option related to preserving hyperlinks or booksmarks in the pdf, just enable it and click "Save". Normally, hyperlinks will be conserved.

Comment: @Thinkr... save as plus "printing for electronic" did the trick. Please convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept. THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome, I did that. I've also included the actual instructions and a screenshot from the associated Microsoft article ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using "Save As" to save your document, make sure the file format is set to "**PDF**" and the "**Best for electronic distribution and accessibility**" option is the one being used<sup>1</sup>.

This will make hyperlinks work in the exported document (PDF).

For more information, see [Save or convert to PDF or XPS in Office Desktop apps - Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/save-or-convert-to-pdf-or-xps-in-office-desktop-apps-d85416c5-7d77-4fd6-a216-6f4bf7c7c110#ID0EBBH=macOS).

> [image: Screenshot taken on Mac from the above-linked Microsoft support article (https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/save-or-convert-to-pdf-or-xps-in-office-desktop-apps-d85416c5-7d77-4fd6-a216-6f4bf7c7c110#ID0EBBH=macOS) when saving a word document as and the above-described settings]

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Maybe you were using the "Best for printing" option, it is mentioned in the above-linked article that: *"When using Best for printing, the hyperlinks may not convert correctly. This is a known issue in Word for Mac."*</sup>

Comment: I just tried with Word 16.80 and got a working hyperlink also with "Best for printing".

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this seamlessly on a Mac is to just **go to the cloud version of Office 365/Word** (or whatever they call it these days), open your file, and go to **File > Print**.  The software will create a PDF and present a dialog box to open in another tab; from there you can download or open in Preview.

Comment: Did you actually test this? I just tried with Word 16.80 and macOS Sonoma 14.2. Printing to PDF created a PDF with a blue/underlined text but without an active link to click on. Are additional options in the print dialog required maybe?

Comment: I have Word Version 16.80 (23121017) on 14.1.2 (23B92).  As you noted, Printing to PDF yielded the same results as you got.  The results above come from the cloud version of Word.  Apologies for not making that plainer.